# Chrome Master Preferences Location

Tags: google-chrome, preferences

I am trying to set up a chrome master preferences file so that all the students in my school have the correct tabs pre-opened when they launch chrome for the first time.  I am following the instructions, [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en).

However, placing the master_preferences file in either of the locations mentioned in the article works.  Has anyone else had any success setting this up on Mac OSX?

The locations I am trying are:
    ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Google Master Preferences File/master_preferences

and 
    /Library/Google/Google Chrome Master Preferences/master_preferences

I am also trying renaming the master_preferences file to 'Google Chrome Master Preferences' in both of those locations.  So far no permutation of their instructions seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Google Master Preferences File/master_preferences
```

But the support page says to use

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Google Chrome Master Preferences
```

In other words, the directory is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`, and the file name is `Google Chrome Master Preferences`. (The file name is `master_preferences` on Windows, not on Mac.)